# Laravel Image Serve Returning Blank

Tags: php, laravel

I serve my images with a controller and it used to work. I'm not sure if I damaged the code by mistake, if it was an upgrade (I just upgraded to version 5.8 but I have a feeling that the images were working for a while after the upgrade) or if it could be Apache related.
I found [this](https://laravel.io/forum/09-03-2014-cant-show-image) and [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/image-is-being-thrown-as-a-white-blank-image) posts which point out to having a space or tab character before the PHP tag. But I already tried everything to remove, if existed, those characters and still not working.
My controller method is like this:

```
public function getPicture($picture){
    $path = Storage::disk('main')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix().$picture;

    $file = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    return $response->header("Content-type", $type);
}
```

And all I get is a blank square...   =(

Comment: have you tried using the response() helper instead?  https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#file-responses

Comment: hadn't tried. but just did response()->file($path)  or response()->file($path, ['Content-type'=>'image/jpeg') and neither worked

Comment: If you're right and you have a space/tab somewhere you shouldn't, try clearing the output buffer before the return. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php

Comment: it worked when using the helper only...which is good enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean the output buffer before returning the controller. I also like to use the helper functions from Laravel. So the code would be something like:

```
public function getPicture($picture){
    $path = Storage::disk('main')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix().$picture;

    ob_end_clean();
    return response()->file($path);
}
```